# Program prints all digits from array, prints backwards

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a program that prints all digits from an array (entered as an integer) and it works, but the digits are printed backwards and I don't know how to reverse them. Can someone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


void explode(int number,int array[])
{

   while (number > 0) {
      int digit = number % 10;
      cout << digit << '\n';
      number /= 10;
   }
}


int main()
{
   int digits[100];
   int numdigits;

   int n;
   cout << "Enter number: ";
   cin >> n;

   //  numdigits = explode(n,digits);

   cout << "[";
   while (n > 0) {
      int digit = n % 10;
      n /= 10;
      digits[digit] = digit;
      cout << digits[digit];

   }
   cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because that's how the algorithm you use *work*, it takes the "rightmost" digit first, then the next rightmost etc. Use a debugger to step through your code line by line to see it in action, or just do it on *paper*.

Comment: Okay, so how do I fix my algorithm to work as I want it to (leftmost first)?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to reverse the array using `reverse()` from `<algorithm>`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int array_c = 0;

void explode(int number,int array[])
{
   while (number > 0) {
      int digit = number % 10;
      number /= 10;
      array[array_c++] = digit;
   }
}


int main()
{
   int digits[100];
   int numdigits;

   int n;
   cout << "Enter number: ";
   cin >> n;

   explode(n,digits);
   reverse(digits,digits+array_c);
   cout << "[";
   for(int i = 0; i < array_c; ++i)
        cout<<digits[i];
   cout << "]" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of

```
digits[digit] = digit;
```

is not right. You probably meant to use

```
digits[numdigits] = digit;
```

You can fix your problem by dividing the work into two steps. In the first step, you store the digits. In the second step, you print the digits.

```
int numdigits = 0;
while (n > 0) {
   cout << "n: " << n << endl;
   int digit = n % 10;
   n /= 10;
   digits[numdigits++] = digit;
}

// Make sure to print them in reverse order.

cout << "[";
for ( ; numdigits > 0; )
{
   cout << digits[--numdigits];
}
cout << "]" << endl;
```